# How to check the succession of a character

Tags: c#, .net, string

I want to check how many successing spaces are in my string. It should be no more than one.

For example:

```
this is ok
this  is NOT ok
thisisok
this   is NOT ok
```

Comment: With *successing* you mean continuous?

Comment: yes, i think i chose my words poorly. I mean consecutive repeating or continuous

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335371/check-does-string-contain-more-than-one-white-space

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The question you marked as a duplicate is not a duplicate of this question.  This question is asking about successive strings while the duplicate is substrings appearing anywhere in the full string.  The question Habib linked to is a more appropriate duplicate.

Comment: @JohnKoerner just reopen and dupelhammer as duplicate provided by Habbib - it is actually exact duplicate (the one I provided requires some thinking before applying as I've added in previous comment). And have more specific code then your good answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test to see if two consecutive spaces exist in the string, as that will also cover any string of spaces longer than 2. You can do this using the `Contains` method:

```
string testString = "this  is not OK";
if (testString.Contains("  "))
{
    // Bad
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the logic for succession spaces in string literal

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "this  is NOT ok";
        int index = str.IndexOf(' ');
       //check if next character of space is also a space
        if (index >= 0 && str[index + 1] == ' ')
            Console.WriteLine("Not Ok String");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("OK String");
    }
```

Comment: Due to good chance of off-by-one and out-of-range error I'd not recommend this code... "You missed this and that ".